# Custom timer job deployed succesfully and running at speficied interval, but not showing in Job definition

Tags: 2010

I have created a custom Timer job for SP2010 and deployed it into farm environment, which has 2 WFE servers and one application server. Timer job is running at the specified interval.But the created job is not showing in job definition.Timer job scoped at "Web".

Can anyone suggest, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail on the method you're using to deploy the timer job, how you know it's running, and what you mean by "Timer job scoped at Web"?

Comment: Hi Rob, I have created a custom timer job with feature which is scoped for "Web". This timer job will be created while activating the feature.In development environment it is working fine.Development environment is a standalone server.I have successfully deployed this timer service into production environement, which has 2 WFE servers and an application server. The functionality of this timer job is to read the Xml data and updates it into sharepoint list libraries.Data's are successfully update into list libraries. But the issue is the created timer job is not showing in job definition.

Comment: It could be a problem with naming, scope, lock type, just about anything.  Can you post the code from your feature receiver that you're using to create the job definition?

Answer (score 1):

In Job definitions there is a 'Scheduled Jobs' section in the top. Try filtering the job definitions by selecting your web application (The web application where you have deployed) name on the right top and move through all the pages in the pagination below. You would be able to see the Timer job.

Answer (score 0):

Scope your timer job to **"WebApplication"** instead